# Test of Group Invariance with 3 Groups

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, group-differences, lavaan

Say, we have three groups and we want to run a test of group invariance with the following data.

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:300,
  group = as.factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"),each=100)),
  x1 = round(rnorm(300, 3.00, 0.50),2),
  x2 = round(rnorm(300, 3.00, 0.50),2))
  df$dv <- round(.20*df$x1 + .30*df$x2+ rnorm(300, 0, 1),2)
```

The model with configural invariance is as follows:

```
library(lavaan)
m1 <- ' 
dv ~ x1 + x2 
'
fit <- sem(m1, estimator="ML", data=df, group="group") 
summary(fit, fit.measures=T)
```

The output we get is

```
lavaan 0.6.15 ended normally after 52 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        12

  Number of observations per group:                   
    a                                              100
    b                                              100
    c                                              100

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0
  Test statistic for each group:
    a                                            0.000
    b                                            0.000
    c                                            0.000

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                                 6.897
  Degrees of freedom                                 6
  P-value                                        0.330

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.000

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)               -409.471
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)       -409.471
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                                 842.943
  Bayesian (BIC)                               887.388
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)        849.331

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.000
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                       NA
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                       NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.000

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured


Group 1 [a]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1                0.033    0.188    0.176    0.860
    x2                0.143    0.180    0.798    0.425

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.873    0.718    1.215    0.224

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.863    0.122    7.071    0.000


Group 2 [b]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1                0.364    0.195    1.872    0.061
    x2                0.047    0.180    0.259    0.796

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.285    0.806    0.354    0.724

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.999    0.141    7.071    0.000


Group 3 [c]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1               -0.291    0.192   -1.513    0.130
    x2               -0.148    0.199   -0.747    0.455

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                2.847    0.861    3.306    0.001

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.838    0.119    7.071    0.000
```

Now, let's impose to the above model a path-equality constraint with the following group ordering 
Group 1 = [a] 
Group 2 = [b] 
Group 3 = [c] 
Let's call this model, **Model abc**

```
fit_abc <- sem(m1, estimator="ML", data=df, group="group",
             group.equal=c("regressions"),
             group.label=c("a","b","c")) 
summary(fit_abc, fit.measures=T)
```

The output is as follows:

```
lavaan 0.6.15 ended normally after 28 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        12
  Number of equality constraints                     4

  Number of observations per group:                   
    a                                              100
    b                                              100
    c                                              100

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 6.665
  Degrees of freedom                                 4
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.155
  Test statistic for each group:
    a                                            0.387
    b                                            2.699
    c                                            3.579

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                                 6.897
  Degrees of freedom                                 6
  P-value                                        0.330

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                      -3.458

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)               -412.804
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)       -409.471
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                                 841.608
  Bayesian (BIC)                               871.238
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)        845.867

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.082
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.187
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.255
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.590

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.045

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured


Group 1 [a]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1      (.p1.)    0.043    0.111    0.384    0.701
    x2      (.p2.)    0.032    0.108    0.293    0.770

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.179    0.461    2.557    0.011

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.867    0.123    7.071    0.000


Group 2 [b]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1      (.p1.)    0.043    0.111    0.384    0.701
    x2      (.p2.)    0.032    0.108    0.293    0.770

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.302    0.470    2.768    0.006

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.026    0.145    7.071    0.000


Group 3 [c]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1      (.p1.)    0.043    0.111    0.384    0.701
    x2      (.p2.)    0.032    0.108    0.293    0.770

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.294    0.469    2.760    0.006

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.869    0.123    7.071    0.000
```

Now, let's rerun the same model - let's call it **Model bac** - by changing the order of groups by 
Group 1 = [b] 
Group 2 = [a] 
Group 3 = [c] 
```

```
fit_bac <- sem(m1, estimator="ML", data=df, group="group",
              group.equal=c("regressions"),
              group.label=c("b", "a", "c")) 
summary(fit_bac, fit.measures=T)
```

The output will be exactly the same as above, with the only difference the ordering of the groups

```
lavaan 0.6.15 ended normally after 28 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        12
  Number of equality constraints                     4

  Number of observations per group:                   
    b                                              100
    a                                              100
    c                                              100

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 6.665
  Degrees of freedom                                 4
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.155
  Test statistic for each group:
    b                                            2.699
    a                                            0.387
    c                                            3.579

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                                 6.897
  Degrees of freedom                                 6
  P-value                                        0.330

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                      -3.458

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)               -412.804
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)       -409.471
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                                 841.608
  Bayesian (BIC)                               871.238
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (SABIC)        845.867

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.082
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.187
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.255
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.590

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.045

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured


Group 1 [b]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1      (.p1.)    0.043    0.111    0.384    0.701
    x2      (.p2.)    0.032    0.108    0.293    0.770

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.302    0.470    2.768    0.006

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.026    0.145    7.071    0.000


Group 2 [a]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1      (.p1.)    0.043    0.111    0.384    0.701
    x2      (.p2.)    0.032    0.108    0.293    0.770

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.179    0.461    2.557    0.011

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.867    0.123    7.071    0.000


Group 3 [c]:

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  dv ~                                                
    x1      (.p1.)    0.043    0.111    0.384    0.701
    x2      (.p2.)    0.032    0.108    0.293    0.770

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                1.294    0.469    2.760    0.006

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .dv                0.869    0.123    7.071    0.000
```

If we inspect the equality constraints for **Model abc** through lavTestScore

```
lavTestScore(fit_abc)
```

we get this

```
$test

total score test:

   test    X2 df p.value
1 score 6.565  4   0.161

$uni

univariate score tests:

   lhs op   rhs    X2 df p.value
1 .p1. == .p10. 3.899  1   0.048
2 .p1. == .p19. 4.054  1   0.044
3 .p2. == .p11. 0.008  1   0.930
4 .p2. == .p20. 0.856  1   0.355
```

My take is that for this model (**Model abc**, where the group order is a, b, c), 
line #1 compares the first regression coefficient of group a with group b and 
line #2 compares the first regression coefficient of group a with group c

If, however, we inspect the equality constraints for **Model bac** through lavTestScore

```
lavTestScore(fit_bac)
```

we get this

```
$test

total score test:

   test    X2 df p.value
1 score 6.565  4   0.161

$uni

univariate score tests:

   lhs op   rhs    X2 df p.value
1 .p1. == .p10. 0.002  1   0.963
2 .p1. == .p19. 4.054  1   0.044
3 .p2. == .p11. 0.610  1   0.435
4 .p2. == .p20. 0.856  1   0.355
```

Based on the above logic, 
line #1 compares the first group with the second (so, again, "b" with "a"), and 
line #2 compares the first with the third group (i.e., now "b" with "c"). 
I would expect lines #1 from the two lavTestScore outputs to be the same and lines #2 to differ. But it seems that this is not the case.  Instead, lines #2 are the same, and lines #1 differ. 
Obviously, I miss a piece of critical information about how comparisons are conducted, but I could not find any hint about this issue. Any hint or help will be much appreciated.
Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Cross-posted on the lavaan forum, where an answer was provided: https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/h5S5BUZM1v0

Comment: No answer has been provided there, either. The full output is exhibited above, and despite the comment that the above issue has been posted elsewhere, the question remains: Why do the results not match when changing the group order?

Comment: A reproducible example (reprex) includes enough data and syntax to create the output, not merely the output about which you have a question.  Your response on the lavaan forum also did not provide a reprex, so it is not clear whether you understood and implemented my suggestion.  If you cannot provide your own real data to post a reprex, you can use simulated data or some other public data (e.g., from the lavaan package) to show the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your syntax, it is difficult to understand what you actually specified. Also, have you considered running a nested model comparison first (as an omnibus test of differences in path coefficients between all 3 groups)? That is, specify two models: one in which the path coefficients are free to vary across groups and one in which they are constrained to be equal across groups. Then, you can run a chi-square difference test between the two models to see if there are any differences between the groups regarding the path coefficients.

Comment: Thanks Cristian for the feedback. I tried to clarify my question by adding more info (and the output)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yves Rosseel (the founder of lavaan), we found why this seeming inconsistency in the chi-square univariate test appears when group ordering is changed.
In a sequence of grouping a-b-c, the first chi-square value corresponds to the release constraint of the group "a" vs. the other two groups, *combined* (i.e., "b" and "c"). So, when the group ordering changes to b-a-c, the release constraint refers to group "b" against the groups "a" and "c", *combined*.
Yves has cross-checked it and confirmed that this is the case.
So, everything seems fine and in good order.